# Variables are same for all Epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am experimenting the image classifier using CNN with keras

My code -

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(224, 224, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(5, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='rmsprop',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.summary()

check=ModelCheckpoint(filepath=r'C:\Users\softloft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\Untitled Folder\i_models.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only = True)

history=model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=100,
    epochs=30,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    shuffle=True,
    callbacks=[check],
)
```

I run this code with one CNN layer and it gives val_acc of about 71.

Then, I add another CNN layer(which is the above code) and it gives the result -

```
Train on 3242 samples, validate on 1081 samples
Epoch 1/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.0773 - acc: 0.1771 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 13.82190, saving model to i_models.hdf5
Epoch 2/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00002: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 3/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 4/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 5/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 6/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 234s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 7/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 8/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 9/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 10/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 11/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 12/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 13/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 14/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 15/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 16/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00016: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 17/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00017: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 18/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00018: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 19/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00019: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 20/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00020: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 21/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00021: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 22/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 72ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00022: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 23/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00023: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 24/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00024: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 25/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00025: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 26/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00026: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 27/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 235s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00027: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 28/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00028: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 29/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00029: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
Epoch 30/30
3242/3242 [==============================] - 236s 73ms/step - loss: 13.2345 - acc: 0.1789 - val_loss: 13.8219 - val_acc: 0.1425

Epoch 00030: val_loss did not improve from 13.82190
```

What happens and what to do..

How all the variables are same for all epochs

thank you

Comment: what is the size of your data?

Comment: Total images are 4323. Training images - 32142 and, Testing images - 1081

Comment: So your training data set is bigger then total dataset?

Comment: Oh sorry, Total images are 4323. Training images - 3242 and, Testing images - 1081

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "rmsprop")
```

to

```
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = 'adam')
```